# undefined method `first_name' for #<Profile id: nil>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trace: https://i.gyazo.com/6487f4eee162e8c2207d7fdb5fc4ef3b.png
I can't get what's happening, I did the same process with the contact page and everything worked fine. Any ideas?

profile/new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1 class="text-center">Create Your Profile</h1>
    <p class="text-center">Be a part of the DevMatch community and fill out your profile!</p>
    <div class="well">
      <%= render 'form' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

profile/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :job_title %>
    <%= f.select :job_title, ['Developer', 'Entrepreneur', 'Investor'], {}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :phone_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :contact_email %>
    <%= f.text_field :contact_email, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Update Profile", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

schema

```
create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "job_title"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.string   "contact_email"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end
```

Profiles controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  # GET to /users/:user_id/profile/new
  def new
    # Render blank profile details form
    @profile = Profile.new
  end
end
```

I get the rror in the profile creator page. It says the firstname is undefined but I tried deleting it and then it says that the laast name is undefined and so on

If I delete the "<%= render 'form' %>" form the other html, the page loads perfectly, but I need a form and I am trying to learn Ruby. Sorry

Comment: Please post code, not links to images. But the profile instance is nil, so you can't call instance methods on it.

Comment: Please post you codebase.

Comment: Probably the error is elsewhere, show the controller code. Looks like you don't actually any object in `@profile`

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: Please post a backtrace

Comment: Please post full backtrace in the question

Comment: Do you run `rake db:migrate`? Also what is the result of `Profile.column_names` when you run in the console?

Comment: I just ran rake db:migrate and it changed happened this: https://gyazo.com/79a2fb9375b2322452992cf0a08ac2d4

Comment: I didn't get you. Is the error resolved now?

Comment: No, still the same error. It just changed something in the schema

Comment: What does this `Profile.column_names` give you in the console?

Comment: it just says "id". I think I am just gonna start form the beginning again

Comment: That means your migrations didn't run properly so you don't have columns in profiles table

Answer (score 1):

> undefined method `first_name' for Profile id: nil
>
> It says the firstname is undefined but I tried deleting it and then it
>   says that the last name is undefined and so on

You didn't have *columns in the profiles table*. You should run `rake db:migrate` to migrate the columns which should resolve your problem.

Additionally always *make sure your migrations are run properly without any errors* You check the *status of the pending migrations* with `rake db:migrate:status`

Comment: I am just gonna start again the profile table, can anyone tell me how to go back from github to cloud9?